# HSQLDB: Embedding Text table within application jar file

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

I want to embed a HSQLDB database within the application jar file. I'm using a text table. I know I can connect to the database using `jdbc:hsqldb:res:` protocol to connect to the database within jar file. But how do I specify the source of the table in `.script` file?

`SET TABLE PUBLIC.MYTABLE SOURCE '<what_path_do_I_specify_here>'`

Answer (score 0):

If you put the text source files in the same directory as the .script file, then the SOURCE path is just the name of the file. For example if the text file is `tabledata.csv`, the statement should be

```
SET TABLE PUBLIC.MYTABLE SOURCE 'tabledata.csv'
```

Comment: But what if my .script file and the text file is within the jar file? Specifying just the file name doesn't seem to work then!